# Why does XPath.selectNodes(context) always use the whole document in JDOM

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jdom

I'm trying to run the same query on several different contexts, but I always get the same result.
This is an example xml:

```
<root>
<p>
  <r>
    <t>text</t>
  </r>
</p>
<t>text2</t>
</root>
```

So this is what I'm doing:

```
final XPath xpath = XPath.newInstance("//t");

List<Element> result = xpath.selectNodes(thisIsThePelement); 
// and I've debuged it, it really is the <p> element
```

And I always get both `<t>` elements in the result list.
I need just the `<t>` inside the `<p>` I'm passing to the `XPath` object.

Any ideas would be of great help, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using `"//t"` as your XPath expression, which means precisely "find all `t` elements in the document".

To only find the *descendant* `t` elements from the context node, use `".//t"`.

See the ["abbreviated syntax"](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) part of the XPath spec for more details.

Comment: Can't thank you enough, thanks for not just saying "read this" :) It seems my xpath knowledge is not as much as it needs to be.